# How to have Decimal point in Input Mask

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I am using http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask

I can't derive a pattern to my need.

The possibilities I have

99x99x99

99.99x99x99

99x99.99x99

99x99x99.99

99.99x99.99x99

99x99.99x99.99

99.99x99.99x99.99

> $('selector').inputmask({mask: '99[.99]X99[.99]X99[.99]', greedy: false });

if the user only wants to input 99x99.99x99 its displayed as

```
> 99.__x99.99x99.__
```

So haw can I remove those .___ as the mask is waiting for the decimal point with the dot

Could someone help me with this :(

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$('selector').inputmask({mask: '99[.99]X99[.99]X99[.99]', "placeholder": "" });
```

Comment: Thank you, The dot is displayed .x.x. and for the first x its fitting but it mess up when i further enter.